# Delete Emails from Outlook Folder Using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, outlook, delete-file

I can't seem to get this working. I am trying to iterate through all the mail items in a folder I created named 'SlaughterPDFs' and delete the emails.

Below is the code I am using. In this code I was just trying to delete the mail items out of the outlook 'Drafts' folder.

```
public void deleteMails()
{
    Application tempApp = new Application();
    MAPIFolder tempInbox = default(MAPIFolder);
    Items JunkItems = default(Items);

    tempInbox = tempApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").
        GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
    JunkItems = tempInbox.Items;
    MailItem DeleteMail = default(MailItem);
    foreach (object newMail_loopVariable in JunkItems)
    {
        DeleteMail = (MailItem)newMail_loopVariable;
        DeleteMail.Delete();
    }
    JunkItems = null;
    tempInbox = null;
    tempApp = null;
}
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Or should I be moving these emails to a new folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are having an issue.
If you replace your for loop with the below while loop it should delete all emails in the folder.

```
while (tempInbox.Items.Count > 0)
{
    DeleteMail = (MailItem)tempInbox.Items.GetFirst();
    DeleteMail.Delete();
}
```

If you are having trouble accessing the folder I would use (assuming SlaughterPDFs is a sub folder of inbox):

```
tempInbox = tempApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").
                 GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
tempInbox = tempInbox.Folders["SlaughterPDFs"];
```